# Application Marketplace Submission Error: can not connect to server please try again later

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, marketplace

I'm having a strange and bizarre error message when I try to upload my app for submission in the app store.

The app is a video browser app with embedded videos in the XAP package, it's around **90 Mega bytes in size.**

When I start uploading It says saving for about 20 minutes and then gives the error. (error can not connect to server please try again later).

I checked everything, I updated the assembly meta data (copyright, company and the other stuff), I also verified the app against the submission rules, I also monitored it using the Marketplace Test Kit.

It's really strange, I read other forum post on the app hub and checked all the advises but nothing really helped

Anyone faced this before?

Comment: Are you using IE to upload? I've had trouble accessing marketplace submission in Firefox.

Comment: @Waleed somewhat unrelated, but I doubt I'd download your app if it was 90 MB. It better have a pretty good reason to be that big (i.e. if you can link to youtube instead for something, then do it)

Comment: @willmel: some games are more than 150 Megas so this is not an issue since the max allowed size is 225 Megas

Comment: @terphi, I'm using firefox, I'll try IE

Comment: @Waleed but when I'm downloading a game, I expect it. It has models, sounds, music, etc. When I'm just trying to download an app, it's different.

Comment: It's kind of a video dictionary educational app (Sign Language), the embedded videos are proprietary and need to be protected, I'm just the developer responsible for it in my company, that's why I need to take care of submission also.

Comment: Waleed ok, I understand :) Note though that if I get the .xap, its trivial to get all the videos that are embedded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happened to me before, app hubs just really buggy. Leave it a few mins and try another web browser.

Answer (score 0):

Get a better/faster internet connection, and try another browser. That's all you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly App Hub has a 180 sec upload timeout (it was confirmed to me by App Hub team member) so if you have internet connection not fast enough and xap big enough you have no chance to upload it. A possible workaround is to upload it from a dedicated host.